# Twilio creating confrence

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

Having trouble in creating conference. i need to achieve where when the agent is having conversation with a client the agent can add another person in the room. I research some documentation but it's just transferring the caller to the conference and the conference creator is not in the conference.

Comment: How the agent can transfer himself to the conference? is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The best thing to look at will be [this blog post on warm transfers using Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/warm-phone-call-transfers-with-python-flask-and-twilio-voice.html). It is in Python, but the theory is the same.

The basic idea is that you get the first two people into a [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference) first. Then you can make a new call to the third person you want to bring in and drop them into the same conference which adds them to the call.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Hi philnash thank you for your answer. But i have one more question is it possible to add a participant to conference without calling them?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The person needs to be on the phone to be in a conference call.

Comment: For example the iam having conversation with friend1 and i want to add another participant which is friend2 on the conversation. Is it possible to have conference while iam having conversation with friend1?.

Comment: You can add them to the conference, but they either have to call into your number or you have to generate a call from the Twilio API to them.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I can add both of my friend1 and my friend2 to the conference. The problem is the person adding is not in the conference. How will conference creator transfer himself to the conference is that possible without calling?

Comment: What is the person adding other people to the conference doing? How do you want to add them to the conference? Are they already on the phone?

Comment: I will give real life scenario. An agent talking to a client. And the client request to add another person in the call. So the agent will add the requested person on the call but first the agent need to create conference so that the client, the agent, and the requested person can talk to each other. In my system i can add both of the client and the requested person on the conference but after i add both of them i don't know how the agent can go to that conference.  Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: I would start with them in a conference call, initially between two people and then adding the third.

Comment: but any do you have any idea how to achieve this? Any documentation that i can reference?

Comment: That blog post I linked above on warm transfers is the best description.

Comment: Thank you very much i will try my best to achieve this. But i have last question but it's more on technical side. Because To be able to add a person to the conference you need to have a callsid which is can get while you are on a call. So the question is can twilio add a participant to conference using a phone number?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123772/discussion-between-jann-anthony-briza-and-philnash).